# Panorama API - Inflate layout on top of panorama view

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-street-view, panorama-control

I'm using google play services panorama api fir displaying panorama image.
Everything works fine but I want to add a layout on top of that view so the image will be used as an activity background.

Here's my code for showing the panoramic view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
       .addApi(Panorama.API)
       .build();
 }

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.pano1);
        Panorama.PanoramaApi.loadPanoramaInfo(mClient, uri).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<PanoramaApi.PanoramaResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(PanoramaApi.PanoramaResult result) {
                        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Intent viewerIntent = result.getViewerIntent();
                            Log.i(TAG, "found viewerIntent: " + viewerIntent);
                            if (viewerIntent != null) {
                                startActivity(viewerIntent);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + result);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

The workflow is that I start new activity with the ViewerIntent and I don't have layout control so it just showing the panoramic view.

I'm searching one of the following:

- Getting control of the openning ViewerIntent activity
- Passing a layout to the next activity through bundle
- overriding the panoramic view activity, and populating my own layout

Google street view panorama activity example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for post question. It's help me make demo for panorama.

Answer (score 0):

The Panorama API  in the Google APIs doesn't seem to have that much feature that you're looking for. Based on the return description of the PanoramaResult (`getViewerIntent`),

> If the image is a panorama this is not null and will launch a viewer when started. If the image is not a panorama this will be null.

You may have to search for a 3rd party library or create your own implementation on the requirements you need.

Comment: google street view app has a layout on top of the panorama activity, they even have a transparent toolbar at the top and a scrollable panel from bottom. That's exactly what i'm searching for, but I couldn't find any relevant reference for that. Are you familiar with any library that might match this requirements?